# PowerShell - How to get Environment Variable and Join-Path to work in single step

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

When I do the following:

```
$folderpath = join-path [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") 'Final'
```

I get this error:

> Join-Path : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'Final'. At line:1 char:15 + ... olderpath = join-path
>   [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") 'Final' ... +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingException
>   
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

So I have to do the following instead:

```
$folderpath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$folderpath = join-path $folderpath 'Final'
```

which gives me `C:\Users\AMS\Desktop\Final`, which is what I want.

Is there a way to do the above in one step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the environment variable in brackets:

```
$folderpath = join-path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) 'Final'
```